# Visual Studio Code views/tabs seems broken

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having some issues on Visual Studio Code, views (i.e. tabs without an editor) are broken and don't display correctly their content.

In example, some extensions like Git Graph or Diff Folders show an empty window

[image]

[image]

and even description tabs on extension pages don't display anything

[image]

[image]

I'm using version 1.60.2 on an openSUSE powered machine, downloaded from the official repos from Microsoft.

I've already tried to clean caches, start from scratch with a new configuration folder, and even downgrade to a previous version of VS Code, but the problem still persists.

Somebody can help me troubleshoot this problem and try to fix it?

Are there some logs where I can find more info about this problem and troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did this just happen, has it worked before? Did you disable all Extensions? Themes?

Comment: Yes, it happened all of a sudden. It was working ok before. Like I said I tried to rename the configuration folder from `~/.config/Code` to start with a clean and empty configuration, and it still happens. Also tried from another Linux user profile, it still happens, and also tried to downgrade to a previous version. I'm rather clueless right now :)

Comment: From your screenshot, I'm seeing a Theme and Extensions running.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the trials. But this happens also on the conditions I have mentioned. Like I said this error appears mostly with extension panels.

Comment: it is not the usual display of the cause but have you tried running with `graphics acceleration disabled`, have you looked with the DevTools if there is is something in those tabs but that they are grey on grey

Comment: You could also check the developer console going to "Help -> Toggle Developer Tools" in case there's any error messages that could help you understand what's happening.

Comment: Just making sure, did you try to completely uninstall VSCode and then re-install it?

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your support, it was a bug that was corrected in the latest release https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/134451